# Using GetElementsById to search a website

Tags: c#, html, linq, filter

```
string entry = Titleentry.Text;

HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection;
HtmlDocument filters = webBrowser1.Document;

theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
    if ((curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "searchTitle"))
    {
        curElement.SetAttribute("value", entry);
    }
}

filters.GetElementById("filterSortBy").GetAttribute("option").Select("price_low_high");

theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
    if (curElement.GetAttribute("id").Equals("searchSubmit"))
    {
        curElement.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

the marked statement gives me the following message:

> Error  1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

what I am trying to do is get elements by ID from a website since if i try elements by tag name it is choosing the incorrect element

I tried using html collections but it says cannot implicitly convert html elements to html collections

Comment: anyone care to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

First, `Select` takes a `Func<TSource, TResult>`, not just a string saying what you want. Second, why are you attempting to use `Select` in the first place? `GetAttribute` returns a string of the attribute's value. Just declare a string to capture the value.

```
string option = filters.GetElementById("filterSortBy").GetAttribute("option");
```

Comment: I am using Select because its a list of options and since im very newbie in c# I tought that was the common sense since its a selection. After using that how can I select the price low to high option value?